# profile picture upload laravel & foundation framework

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-4, zurb-foundation

I have a registration form completed and would like to add a profile picture upload. Once the user clicks the browse, he can select the photo. Then he clicks ok/apply/ok and then the photo is reflected in the thumbnail area without page refreshing.

Once the user is happy with all fields input he can submit the form and with it the photo of course.

Anything that does this exists out there already? If not, please provide guidance on how to establish this feature.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of a ready made solution for this but there probably is something :-)

However, with Laravel this is beautifully simple. You've tagged your question ajax but I'll answer this assuming you're going to use an old fashioned server round trip (i.e a form submit).

1) In your template, add a file element to the form. http://laravel.com/docs/html#file-input

2) Add some javascript to the page that detects when a file is selected and shows the preview. Extensive tutorial here: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

3) In your controller, handle the file using the `Input` facade. http://laravel.com/docs/requests#files

Comment: Thanks Dave. Will follow the links.